# UIImage / tapgesturerecognizer / New view

Tags: uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am populating a tableView from data in a plist.  When I select a cell I use prepareForSegue and indexPathForSelectedRow to bring the plist data to a detail view controller (DVC).  In the DVC I have a UIImageView that loads a particular image using a switch statement, depending upon the row that was selected in the tableView.  This is all working correctly.

I want to add a tapGestureRecognizer to my UIImageView so that a tap on the image in my DVC brings up a new view controller.  In that view controller I have a UIImageView on a UIScrollView.  I want the image from the DVC to load into the next view controller so that I can zoom and pan the image.

I'm using storyboards.  I made sure the UIImageView in my DVC has user interaction enabled, and I added a tapGestureRecognizer to it via drag and drop.  I then created a segue from the tapGestureRecognizer to my final view controller and ran it in the simulator.  Tapping the image in the DVC fires the last view controller.

What I can't figure out is how to tell the UIImageView in the last view controller to display the image from the DVC, which is always different based on the row selected in the tableView.

I hope that makes sense and someone might have an idea how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Is there any code you can share showing what you have tried?

Comment: I don't even know where to start.  My question is more to the point of, is this even possible and if so, please point me in the right direction.  I'm starting to think maybe a photo viewer may be the way to go.  I'm researching that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  To recap, I needed to pass information from a plist to a  detail view controller based on the row selected in a tableview.  Then, in the detail view controller I wanted to be able to tap an image and have the image open in a new view controller.  The image in the detail view controller was set by the row selected, so it wasn't just a matter of creating the third view controller and setting an image.

Data is being passed from the plist to the detail view controller as a row is selected in the table view.  That is being accomplished here:

tableviewcontroller.m

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *bighornData = _bighornTable[indexPath.row];
        BighornDetailViewController *bhdvc = (BighornDetailViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        bhdvc.bighornData = bighornData;
        bhdvc.bighornZoneNumber = indexPath.row;
    }
```

The image is being set in the detail view controller by the number stored in bighornData.  When I realized the number was stored there even after the detail view controller had loaded, it was a matter of passing that variable on to the final view controller so the image could be set there, as well.

detailviewcontroller.m

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender:(id)sender {
        ImageViewController *ivc = (ImageViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        ivc.bighornZoneNumber = _bighornZoneNumber;

    }
```